# Bundled executable crashes without warning when rendering plots

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, 64-bit, py2exe

(I have already resolved this issue but it cost me two weeks of my time and my employer a couple of grand, so I'm sharing it here to save some poor soul.)

My company is converting our application from 32-bit to 64-bit. We create an executable using py2exe, using the bundle=2 option. The executable started crashing as soon as it tried to render a matplotlib plot.

Versions:

python==2.7.13,

matplotlib==2.0.0,

numpy==1.13.1,

py2exe==0.6.10a1

Answer (score 0):

I tracked the error to the numpy library. Numpy calls numpy.linalg._umath_linalg.inv() and the program abruptly exits with no error message, warning, or traceback.

_umath_linalg is a .pyd file and I discovered that this particular .pyd file doesn't like being called from library.zip, which is where py2exe puts it when using bundle option 2 or 1.

The solution is to exclude numpy in the py2exe setup script and copy the entire package folder into the distribution directory and add that directory to the system path at the top of the main python script.